# C# Passing double array to constructor overload method

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, constructor, overloading

I am learning c# from one book and  I have to write a code on my own as a part of exercise. One of the things to be done is to pass double array to one of the constructor overload method who will handle it further. Problem is that I don't know how to do it.

Here comes the full code (till now):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace assignment01v01
{

    public class Matrix
    {
        int row_matrix; //number of rows for matrix
        int column_matrix; //number of colums for matrix
        int[,] matrix;

        public Matrix() //set matrix size to 0*0
        {
            matrix = new int[0, 0];
            Console.WriteLine("Contructor which sets matrix size to 0*0 executed.\n");
        }

        public Matrix(int quadratic_size) //create quadratic matrix according to parameters passed to this constructor
        {
            row_matrix = column_matrix = quadratic_size;
            matrix = new int[row_matrix, column_matrix];
            Console.WriteLine("Contructor which sets matrix size to quadratic size {0}*{1} executed.\n", row_matrix, column_matrix); 
        }

        public Matrix(int row, int column) //create n*m matrix according to parameters passed to this constructor
        {
            row_matrix = row;
            column_matrix = column;
            matrix = new int[row_matrix, column_matrix];
            Console.WriteLine("Contructor which sets matrix size {0}*{1} executed.\n", row_matrix, column_matrix);
        }

        public Matrix(int [,] double_array) //create n*m matrix and fill it with data passed to this constructor
        {
            matrix = double_array;
            row_matrix = matrix.GetLength(0);
            column_matrix = matrix.GetLength(1);
        }

        public int countRows()
        {
            return row_matrix;
        }

        public int countColumns()
        {
            return column_matrix;
        }

        public float readElement(int row, int colummn)
        {
            return matrix[row, colummn];
        }
    }
 

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Matrix mat01 = new Matrix();

            Matrix mat02 = new Matrix(3);

            Matrix mat03 = new Matrix(2,3);

            //Here comes the problem, how should I do this?
            Matrix mat04 = new Matrix ( [2,3] {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }});           

            //int [,] test = new int [2,3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

        }
    }
}
```

Part of the code that bothers me is marked with "//Here comes the problem, how should I do this?".

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multi dimensional array can be created as follows.

```
 new Matrix(new int[,] {{1, 2, 3,}, {1, 2, 3}});
```

The `int` is even redundant so you can make it even easier (or, at least, it should be easier to read :))

```
 new Matrix(new [,] {{1, 2, 3,}, {1, 2, 3}});
```

Comment: damn "are you human" dialog kept me busy.... what Jared said... :) PS: yes! I am human!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're struggling with how to create a multi-dimensional array with a set of initial values.  The syntax for that is the following

```
new [,] {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }}
```

Because you are initializing the array in this case you don't need to specify a size or a type.  The compiler will infer it from the elements provided

Answer (score 1):

You just have the indices switched, and are missing a `new` keyword. This should work:

```
Matrix mat04 = new Matrix ( new [3,2] {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }});
```

Or, as @JaredPar noted, you can omit the array size completely and have the compiler infer it for you:

```
Matrix mat04 = new Matrix ( new [,] {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }});
```

Comment: Yes I  chose solution with:
Matrix mat04 = new Matrix ( new [,] {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }});